# Removing character from 'type' in cmd batch file

Tags: string, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a text file and I wish to remove its first character with command line batch file.
I cant read the content of the file to a var with `set /p var= <myfile` because its a big file ( > 8KB)
I just need the first character, if its a whitespace, to remove it.

Comment: If you want to remove one character from a file, you must read the file, edit the file, store it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GnuSed:

```
@echo off
sed "1s/^[ \t]//" file.txt >file2.txt
```

Thanks to Endoro for the simplification.

Comment: to delete the first character from the first line of a file `sed "1s/^.//" infile > outfile`  works :)

Comment: Thanks @endoro   :)  I used your method in the answer.